# Java 2D animation library

Tags: java, 2d

I am working on an app where users will be performing a lot of drag and drop. I looking for a 2D java animation library that will support drawing simple cartoon figures and allows dragging and dropping items. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`java.awt.dnd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/package-summary.html) Drag & Drop package to start. This package contains the basics of what you'll need for drag and drop. As for animation, Java has enough out of the box in the AWT toolkit for simple animation. If you find that you need something more fully-featured, I'd recommend the [Trident](https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) animation library, which certainly has the capabilities to do what you want.